# SVN ignore folders that end in

Tags: svn, svnignore

I'm using Cocostudio and I'm finding that it creates all of the individual frame files for my animations, which I would like to omit from the SVN repository.  All of these images exist in folders that end in `_PList.Dir`, i.e. `myAnimation_Plist.Dir/image1.png`, `myAnimation_Plist.Dir/image2.png`, etc.

So my question is, how do you define an ignore pattern that would match all directories that end in '.Dir'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SVN Book, ["Ignoring Unversioned Items"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) section, "File Patterns in Subversion" topic

`*_Plist.Dir` may be better choice

**Note**

Fast test of ignore-pattern

```
>svn pl -v
Properties on '.':
  svn:ignore
    *_PList.Dir

>svn st --no-ignore
 M      .
I       1_PList.Dir
I       2_PList.Dir
I       3_PList.Dir
?       data.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, presumably because SVN is trying to match this pattern against files rather than folders (because of the .dir), I want to ignore the directory itself.

Comment: @RobJohnson - you miss something, because it works, see my note in answer